# NSTextField: how do I add a search icon as in other apps?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

How can I add a search icon on the left in a NSTextField? You can see the same in many other applications.

Comment: NSSearchField may be what you want.

Answer (score -3):

I guess it is this:

```
text = NSTextField.alloc().initWithFrame_(((0, 0), (30.0, 22.0)))
text.setCell_(NSSearchFieldCell.alloc().init())
```